# How to scale a sprite on x axis to touch the point without changing pivot?

Tags: unity, mathematics, sprites, scale

I have a sprite. The pivot is at random point.

I want to increase the sprite's scale on the x axis, without moving the pivot, until its edge touches a point at right.

I have a method to set/add size. I calculate a distance from the sprite's edge to the point at the right and add it as a size.

The problem is the sprite scale increases its size in both directions of the x axis (left and right), considering the pivot is not at the left edge of the sprite.

How can I scale the sprite while keeping the left edge where it is?

I have:

[image: A white square and red square, with a gap in between]

I want to get:

[image: A white rectangle stretched until it abuts the red square]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
The next method sticks a right side of a gameobject to the point on x axis:

ScaleToStick:

```
private void ScaleToStick(GameObject gameObject, Vector3 target)
{
    Bounds bounds1 = StaticScript.GetBoundsChildren(gameObject);
    float size = target.x - (bounds1.center.x + bounds1.extents.x);
    float distancePivotToCenter = bounds1.center.x - transform.position.x;
    float _1 = distancePivotToCenter + bounds1.extents.x;
    float _2 = distancePivotToCenter - bounds1.extents.x;
    _2 = Mathf.Abs(_2);
    float x = (_1 + _2) / _1;
    size *= x;

    StaticScript.AddSizeUniform(gameObject, size, "x");
}
```

GetBoundsChildren:

```
public static Bounds GetBoundsChildren(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        Bounds bounds = new Bounds();
        bool first = true;

        foreach (Renderer renderer in gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
        {
            if (first)
            {
                first = false;

                if (renderer.bounds.size == Vector3.zero)
                {
                    Bounds bounds_ = new Bounds();
                    bounds_.center = renderer.gameObject.transform.position;
                    bounds = bounds_;
                }
                else
                    bounds = renderer.bounds;
            }
            else
                if (renderer.bounds.size == Vector3.zero)
            {
                Bounds bounds_ = new Bounds();
                bounds_.center = renderer.gameObject.transform.position;
                bounds.Encapsulate(bounds_);
            }
            else
                bounds.Encapsulate(renderer.bounds);
        }

        return bounds;
    }
```

AddSizeUniform:

```
public static void AddSizeUniform(GameObject gameObject, float sizeAdd, string axis)
    {
        Vector3 scaleOld = gameObject.transform.localScale;
        Vector3 sizeOld = GetBoundsChildren(gameObject).size;

        Vector3 scaleNew = Vector3.zero;
        float scaleNewMultiply = 0;

        if (axis == "x")
            scaleNewMultiply = (sizeOld.x + sizeAdd) / sizeOld.x;

        if (axis == "y")
            scaleNewMultiply = (sizeOld.y + sizeAdd) / sizeOld.y;

        if (axis == "z")
            scaleNewMultiply = (sizeOld.z + sizeAdd) / sizeOld.z;

        scaleNew.x = scaleNewMultiply * scaleOld.x;
        scaleNew.y = scaleNewMultiply * scaleOld.y;
        scaleNew.z = scaleNewMultiply * scaleOld.z;

        gameObject.transform.localScale = scaleNew;
    }
```